# Python loads None to Json without emitting error

Tags: python, json, nonetype

I am parsing dictionaries into nested Json (Python 2.7). The problem I have that sometimes there is no value for the variable so it takes None, it depends if the variable came or not. It would be ok, but I want to avoid escape characters before quotations. Before I get nested Json I do `json.loads()` to remove string escapes.

The problem is to return `None` if there is no dict.

Example code:

```
import json

data1 = '{"foo":"bar"}'
data2 = None
sensor = {'header':'Info',
          'data1': json.loads(data1),
          'data2': json.loads(data2)}
output = json.dumps(sensor)
print(output)
```

Expected outcome:

```
{"data2": null, "data1": {"foo": "bar"}, "header": "Info"}
```

Received error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\jsonDecoding.py", line 7, in <module>
    'data2': json.loads(data2)}
  File "\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'NoneType'
```

Tried solution:

```
class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if obj is None::
            return None
        else: return super(Decoder, self).default(obj)

data1 = '{"foo":"bar"}'
data2 = None
sensor = {'header':'Info',
          'data1': json.loads(data1),
          'data2': json.loads(data2, cls=Decoder)}
output = json.dumps(sensor)
```

I thought implementing `Decoder.default()` should solve the problem but it calls the class but does not call the default method.

There are plenty of talks about `None` in place of `key` or `value` but I did not find in place of whole object

Comment: No, the `data2`, should be `'null'`, since you `json.loads` it.

Comment: The `data2` is an original variable from sensor. It comes either as a string in form of `json` in the same format as `data1` or it does not come at all so it is `None`. It never comes as `'null'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you make the problem harder than it is. We can construct a `None`-safe function:

```
def nonesafe_loads(obj):
    if obj is not None:
        return json.loads(obj)
```

This will return the `json.loads(obj)` in case `obj` is *not* `None`, and otherwise it will return `None`. Or we can construct a "best effort" JSON loads, that aims to `json.loads` the string, or in case that fails, returns the `obj` itself:

```
def besteffort_loads(obj):
    try:
        return json.loads(obj)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return obj
```

Now we can just use our `nonesafe_loads` in the program:

```
data1 = '{"foo":"bar"}'
data2 = None
sensor = {'header':'Info',
          'data1': nonesafe_loads(data1),
          'data2': nonesafe_loads(data2)}
output = json.dumps(sensor)
```

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: Probably `ValueError` as well, since it is for instance possible that we already have a non-JSON string, like `blablabla`, and then we want to omit deserialization.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: no in Python-2.x that is a `ValueError`, brackets were indeed missing :)

Comment: Update: In the json library v3.1 +, the exact error for trying to json.loads() a non-JSON string like `blababa`is `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`